# each() function slows down

Tags: javascript, function, each

Sorry, just found I had a bracket in the wrong place! All is well now. Thanks for the help.

I have this each function that fires when I click certain buttons. The function is fast for say the first 10 clicks. However, each time I trigger the function (click a button) the function gets slower and slower. It seems to be taking twice as long on each click. Does anybody know why, and I suppose more importantly, how I can change the code to prevent this?

Thanks!

```
function CollarStyleFunction(){

$('#Collar-Style-Box').children(".Fabrics").children(".SwatchBox").children('img').each(function () {

    var titleIs = this.title;
    if (titleIs==option) {
        $(this).parent().css("display", "inline");
    }

});


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Some other info and code:

The JS loads a XML file and loads 10 fabric swatches into the div (class="Fabrics"):

```
function parse(document){

    $(document).find("Swatch").each(function(){
        $(".Fabrics").append(
            '<div class="SwatchBox">'+
            '<img id="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" title="' + $(this).attr('title') + '" src="img/swatch/' + $(this).attr('name') + '.png">'+
            '</div>'
        );
    });


} //function parse End
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Collar-Style -->

    <div id="Collar-Style" class="Name">Collar Style</div>

    <div id="Collar-Style-Box" class="Box">

        <div id="Collar-Style-Options-Box" class="Options">

            <div class="SwatchBox">
                <img id="Flat-Knit" src="img/options/Flat-Knit.png">
            </div><!-- SwatchBox -->

            <div class="SwatchBox">
                <img id="Self-Fabric" src="img/options/Self-Fabric.png">
            </div><!-- SwatchBox -->

            <div class="SwatchBox">
                <img id="Woven" src="img/options/Woven.png">
            </div><!-- SwatchBox -->

        </div><!-- Collar-Style-Options-Box -->

        <div id="Collar-Style-Fabrics-Box" class="Fabrics">
        </div><!-- Collar-Style-Fabrics-Box -->

    </div><!-- Collar-Style-Box --> 

<!-- Canvas -->

    <div id="Collar-Style-Canvas" class="Canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: As a note: you can write $('#Collar-Style-Box > .Fabrics > .SwatchBox > img') and spare all the children()-functions. Improves readability ;)

Comment: Please show us your HTML so we can help you fix/improve your use of CSS selectors.  Also, are you adding more and more DOM objects each time you run the next click?

Comment: All the buttons are firing this same function, nothing is being added by me (at least nothing that I'm aware of!)

Comment: My first guess, with the code I can see here is that you may be recursively binding the element (binding additional events or creating more nodes INSIDE your event handler). Can you please include more of the code including the part where you are binding the event to this method?

Comment: Hi I'm not sure what "binding the event to this method" is but I have added the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just some comments…

```
> function CollarStyleFunction(event){
```

The *event* parameter is not used, does it serve a purpose?

```
>     $('#Collar-Style-Box').children(".Fabrics").children(".SwatchBox").children('img').each(function (i) {
```

Others have commented on using a selector (which likely will be passed to a native querySelectorAll method) instead of multiple function calls.

The *i* parameter is not used, does it serve a purpose?

```
>     titleIs = $(this).attr('title');
```

The variable *titleIs* becomes global when the above is executed. It should probably be kept local. Also more efficient to just get the title property:

```
var titleIs = this.title;
```

.

```
>     if (titleIs==(option)) {
```

Is *option* initialised elsewhere? There is no need for the parenthesis round *option*:

```
  if (titleIs == option) {
```

.

```
>         $(this).parent().css("display", "inline");
```

Do you really want *inline*? Consider setting display to '' (empty string) so the element can return to its default or inherited value, e.g.:

```
this.parentNode.style.display = '';

>     }
> });
```

Comment: Thanks I have made the changes, it's still slowing down.

Comment: Sorry, just found I had a bracket in the wrong place! All is well now. Thanks for the help.